# selecting django objects with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, django-templates

I have objects of a model displayed in a template with a for loop like this:

```
{% for post in posts %}

 {{post.text}}

{% endfor %}
```

Now I want to attach a button to each post object which holds the post.id value and on clicking the button should make an ajax request that updates a vote attribute on that particular object.

So, I tried adding a button like this:

```
{% for post in posts %}

     {{post.text}}

<input type="submit" value="V" id="upButton" post_id="{{post.id}}"></input>

    {% endfor %}
```

Prior to ajax I just want to see if the buttons are working so I tried checking (using jQuery) if it alerts the post.id value of each post:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $('#upButton').click(function(){
        var post_id = $('#upButton').attr('post_id');
        alert(post_id);
      });
    });
  </script>
```

Only the button on the first object is working. Other buttons are not working. What's happening here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`id` attribute can be set only once per html page.

So the javascript code will refer only to the first element always.

Change it to:

```
<input type="submit" value="V" data-role="upButton" post_id="{{post.id}}"></input>
```

And in the javascript:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $('[data-role=upButton]').click(function(){
        var post_id = $(this).attr('post_id');
        alert(post_id);
      });
    });
  </script>
```

It should work

Comment: avoid post_id=... (not valid HTML) and use data-post-id=... it is a valid HTML

Comment: Yeah, the solution is a little weird. Inventing `data-role` when "role" is clearly just another name for a class is pointless, and adding a nonexistent HTML attribute (post_id) is just plain wrong. I would change the HTML to `<input type="submit" value="V" class="upButton" data-id="{{post.id}}"></input>`. And then two lines of JavaScript need to be changes also - it should be now  `$('.upButton').click(function(){` and `var post_id = $(this).data('id');`

Comment: @LudwikTrammer thanks for the answer. Will change accordingly.

Comment: I disagree. Role is for separating logic from design. Changing a class for any object shouldn't affect the behavior of the page

Comment: @YardenST - that's thinking backward. HTML is not about design, it's about semantics - the structure of your page. That obviously includes `class` attributes. They are not just CSS hooks, and you should not think about them as such. You [do not allude to your design decision](http://www.w3.org/QA/Tips/goodclassnames) while creating `class` names, instead `class` names are based on the **role** of each element. Your design decision are separated in the CSS files and when you change your design, you do not change class names, just CSS definitions.

Comment: Class names are about *purpose* of each element, about the document structure. That has absolutely nothing to do with design. `class` attributes where created, so you can give each element a role (or couple of them) and then use both (!) CSS and JavaScript to decide how elements that serve the given role should look and behave.

Comment: @Ludwik well i'm not totally agree, but thanks for the feedback anyway

Comment: @YardenST look at any popular jQuery tutorial. It's not just my opinion. Using class selectors is a well established pattern. You should probably note that it is much faster than what you propose. When you select by class jQuery will use JavaScript's native `document.getElementsByClassName` method (which is very fast and was created precisely because you are *expected* to select element by class in JavaScript). On the other hand when you select by an attribute jQuery have to iterate through every element in the DOM. As you'd expect, they are benchmark showing it's many factors slower.

Comment: @LudwikTrammer You convinced me. Thanks